# Spring service not injected via @ManagedProperty

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, dependency-injection

Please can you help me with this exception ? I looked in forums but I didn't find any solution. 
I could not find the reason of the nullPointer !
I am working on spring, hibernate and jsf. I could neither insert the bean into database nor get the lines and print them into a dataTable. 
Error :

```
Avertissement:   #{beanMateriel.insert()}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{beanMateriel.insert()}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jsf.bean.BeanMateriel.insert(BeanMateriel.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more

Grave:   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jsf.bean.BeanMateriel.insert(BeanMateriel.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
```

faces-config.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>beanMateriel</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>jsf.bean.BeanMateriel</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>materielBO</property-name>
            <value>#{materielBO}</value>
        </managed-property>
    </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

applicationContext.xml :

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"></property>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/InterventionsDB;create=true"></property>
<property name="username" value="omar"/>
<property name="password" value="omar"/>
</bean>
<aop:config proxy-target-class='true'/>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref = "dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="connection.autoReconnect">true</prop>
            <prop key="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</prop>
            <prop key="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id ="materielDAO" class = "dao.ImplMateriel">
    <property name ="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
<bean id ="materielBO" class = "bo.MaterielImplBO">
    <property name ="materielDAO" ref="materielDAO"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
           classpath*:/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

materiel.xhtml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <title>Fiche Materiel</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
<h:form>
    <h1 style="FONT-SIZE: xx-large; color:#8080C0;font-family:Times New Roman;"></h1>
    <h:panelGrid>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <TD>
                <p:outputLabel for="codem" value="Code Matériel" />
            </TD>
            <td>
             <p:inputText id="codem" value="#{beanMateriel.codem}" label="CodeM" required="true"></p:inputText>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td> <p:outputLabel for="libelle" value="Libellé" /></td>
            <td><p:inputText id="libelle" value="#{beanMateriel.libelle}" required="true" label="Libelle"></p:inputText></td></tr>
        <tr><td> <p:outputLabel for="datemiseenservice" value="Date Mise en Service" /></td>
            <td>  <p:calendar id="datemiseenservice" value="#{calendarView.date2}" required="true" label="datemiseenservice"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td> <p:outputLabel for="marque" value="Marque" /></td>
        <td><p:inputText id="marque" value="#{beanMateriel.marque}" required="true" label="marque"></p:inputText></td></tr>
        <tr><td> <p:outputLabel for="departement" value="Département" /></td>
            <td> <p:inputText id="departement" value="#{beanMateriel.departement}" required="true" label="departement"></p:inputText></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><p:commandButton value="Valider" type="submit" icon="ui-icon-check" action="#{beanMateriel.insert()}" readonly="false"/></td>
        </tr> 
        </table>
        </h:panelGrid>

    <p:dataTable id="table" value="#{beanMateriel.liste}" var="obj">
        <p:column headerText="Code">

                  <h:outputText value="#{obj.codem}"></h:outputText>
              </p:column>
              <p:column headerText="Libelle">
              <h:outputText value="#{obj.libelle}"></h:outputText>
              </p:column>
              <p:column headerText="Marque">

                  <h:outputText value="#{obj.marque}"></h:outputText>
              </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Date mise en service">

                <h:outputText value="#{obj.datemiseenservice}"></h:outputText>
              </p:column>
              <p:column headerText="Département">

                  <h:outputText value="#{obj.departement}"></h:outputText>
              </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="modifier">    
         <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-star" title="Icon Only" action="#{beanMateriel.update()}" immediate="true">

</p:commandButton>

    </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="supprimer">    
                  <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-star" title="Icon Only" action="#{beanMateriel.delete()}" immediate="true">

</p:commandButton>
 </p:column>    
          </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

BeanMateriel.java:

```
@ManagedBean(name="beanMateriel")

public class BeanMateriel implements Serializable{
     private int codem;
     private String libelle;
     private String marque;
     private String datemiseenservice;
     private String departement;
      private List<BeanMateriel> liste; 
     @ManagedProperty(value = "#{materielBO}")
     private MaterielImplBO materielBO; 


    public BeanMateriel() {
       }

    /**
     * @return the materielBO
     */
    public MaterielImplBO getMaterielBO() {
        return materielBO;
    }

    /**
     * @param materielBO the materielBO to set
     */
    public void setMaterielBO(MaterielImplBO materielBO) {
        this.materielBO = materielBO;
    }

    public List<BeanMateriel> getListe() {
        return liste;
    }

    public void setListe(List<BeanMateriel> liste) {
        this.liste = liste;
    }

    public BeanMateriel(int codem, String libelle, String marque, String datemiseenservice, String departement, MaterielImplBO materielBO, List<BeanMateriel> liste) {
        this.codem = codem;
        this.libelle = libelle;
        this.marque = marque;
        this.datemiseenservice = datemiseenservice;
        this.departement = departement;
        this.materielBO = materielBO;
        this.liste = liste;
    }



    public int getCodem() {
        return codem;
    }

    public void setCodem(int codem) {
        this.codem = codem;
    }

    public String getLibelle() {
        return libelle;
    }

    public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
        this.libelle = libelle;
    }

    public String getMarque() {
        return marque;
    }

    public void setMarque(String marque) {
        this.marque = marque;
    }

    public String getDatemiseenservice() {
        return datemiseenservice;
    }

    public void setDatemiseenservice(String datemiseenservice) {
        this.datemiseenservice = datemiseenservice;
    }

    public String getDepartement() {
        return departement;
    }

    public void setDepartement(String departement) {
        this.departement = departement;
    }

    public String insert() {

        materielBO.insert(this);
        getAll();
        return "";
    }

     public String delete() {
         materielBO.delete(this);
         getAll();
        return "";
    }

      public String update() {

          materielBO.update(this);
          getAll();
        return "";
    }


       public void  getAll() {
           setListe(materielBO.getAll());
    }


}
```

ImplMateriel.java :

```
public class ImplMateriel extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IfaceMateriel {
@Autowired
public SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void insert(Materiel obj) {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Materiel obj) {
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(obj);}

    @Override
    public void update(Materiel obj) {
        getHibernateTemplate().merge(obj);
        }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Materiel> getAll() {
        return (List<Materiel>) (Object)getHibernateTemplate().find("from Materiel"); }

}
```

MaterielImplBO.java :

```
public class MaterielImplBO implements MaterielBO {
    private ImplMateriel materielDAO; 

    public ImplMateriel getMaterielDAO() {
        return materielDAO;
    }

    public void setMaterielDAO(ImplMateriel materielDAO) {
        this.materielDAO = materielDAO;
    }
    @Override
    public void insert(BeanMateriel obj) {
    Materiel materiel = new Materiel(); 
    materiel.setCodem(obj.getCodem());
    materiel.setDatemiseenservice(obj.getDatemiseenservice());
    materiel.setDepartement(obj.getDepartement());
    materiel.setLibelle(obj.getLibelle());
    materiel.setMarque(obj.getMarque());
    materielDAO.insert(materiel);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(BeanMateriel obj) {
    Materiel materiel = new Materiel(); 
    materiel.setCodem(obj.getCodem());
     materielDAO.delete(materiel);
    }


    @Override
    public void update(BeanMateriel obj) {
    Materiel materiel = new Materiel(); 
    materiel.setCodem(obj.getCodem());
    materiel.setDatemiseenservice(obj.getDatemiseenservice());
    materiel.setDepartement(obj.getDepartement());
    materiel.setLibelle(obj.getLibelle());
    materiel.setMarque(obj.getMarque());
    materielDAO.update(materiel);
}

    @Override
    public List<BeanMateriel> getAll() {
    List<BeanMateriel> liste = new ArrayList<BeanMateriel>();
    for (Materiel obj: materielDAO.getAll())
    {
        BeanMateriel bean = new BeanMateriel(); 
        bean.setCodem(obj.getCodem());
        bean.setDatemiseenservice(obj.getDatemiseenservice());
        bean.setDepartement(obj.getDepartement());
        bean.setLibelle(obj.getLibelle());
        bean.setMarque(obj.getMarque());
        liste.add(bean);
    }

    return liste;
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You've got a `NullPointerException` in your `insert` method, probably because of your `materielBO` property being null. Check it out.

Comment: @jens It's not the same problem.. I could not resolve this one!

Comment: @XtremeBiker Yes but I really could not find the reason !

Comment: The reason is the bean not getting injected by JSF.

Comment: Well, Spring MVC (I assume it's Spring MVC) and JSF don't relly mix well. Both are MVC frameworks and thus serve the same purpose so you'd be much better off using one or the other.

Comment: Why you initialize bean object in faces-config.xml file as well as through annotation?

Comment: You should be programming to interfaces NOT concrete implementations... So use `MaterialBO` instead of `MaterielImplBO` in your JSF bean. Also I think your design is flawed as you have a JSF dependency in your BO (your `MaterialBean` which is JSF managed is used inside a method of the service and with this you introduce a circulair reference in your package structure!).